# Laravel Dingo Authentication JWT Required on Internal Requests

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, dingo-api

I'm using Laravel Dingo to consume API requests (internally) within Laravel controllers, and have come up against a problem with routes which are authenticated with tokens in headers. I'm getting an Exception thrown, looking for a token in requests.

This is my API routes:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version(['v1'], function ($api) {
 $api->post('/users/addEmployee', "App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@storeEmployee")->middleware('jwt.auth');
}
```

Note the middleware added to the call. When using Postman, this works 100% and adds a new employee.

When calling it internal with Dingo, I get back the typical 'token not found' error that I would typically see from the API when the Authorisation Header is missing.

```
try{
            $dispatcher = app('Dingo\Api\Dispatcher');

            $payload = [
                        'name' => $request->name,
                        'email' => $request->email,
                       ];


            $registerResponse = $dispatcher->be(Auth::user())->with($payload)->post('/api/users/addEmployee');

      catch( InternalHttpException $internal ){
        echo($internal->getResponse());die();
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($v->getErrors());
      }
```

My question is this, do I need to add the token, or is there a way to 'turn off' jwt middleware for an internal request? Does the ->be method not handle all of this within Dingo? p.s. Auth::user is not null, I've checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, you can manually set headers on outbound requests prior to it being dispatched. Didn't see the method anywhere in the docs, but following works.

```
  $token = JWTAuth::fromUser(Auth::user());
  $registerResponse = $this->api->header('Authorization','Bearer:'.$token)->with($payload)->be(Auth::user())->post('/api/users/addEmployee');
```